# Can I view price graphs for alternative currencies, longer than 12 hours?

Tags: litecoin, charts

AFAIK, btc-e.com is the only place to show [LTC/BTC price graph](https://btc-e.com/exchange/ltc_btc). Is there a way to view these graphs for longer than the ~ 12 hours that are shown by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at http://www.cryptocoincharts.info you see long time chart for all alternative crytpo currencies

Answer (score 7):

There is [LTC Charts](http://www.ltc-charts.com) with some long term chart data for LTC/BTC from BTC-E and Vircurex.

Answer (score 1):

Ask btc-e for the data. You can also ask me for some data (on irc or bitcointalk), but I don't have the complete set and it's only BTC/LTC pair.
Here's a postgres dump of the trades I have in my db: http://www.mediafire.com/?q1iis15iv8gc7m6

Answer (score 1):

Here there are some [Litecoin price charts](http://www.litecoinpool.org/charts#market) for a period of one week.